# Streamlip app not searching files in the good directory

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to run a Streamlit app importing `pickle files` and a `DataFrame`. The pathfile for my script is :

> /Users/myname/Documents/Master2/Python/Final_Project/streamlit_app.py

And the one for my `DataFrame` is:

> /Users/myname/Documents/Master2/Python/Final_Project/data/metabolic_syndrome.csv

One could reasonably argue  that I only need to specify `df = pd.read_csv('data/df.csv')` yet it does not work as the Streamlit app is unexpectedly not searching in its directory:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myname/data/metabolic_syndrome.csv'

How can I manage to make the app look for the files in the good directory (the one where it is saved) without having to use absolute pathfiles ?

Comment: did your try `df = pd.read_csv('../data/df.csv')`? By the way `df.csv` is not the same as `metabolic_syndrome.csv` which one are you referring to?

Comment: Many thanks for spotting the typo, I fixed it. As regards your suggestion, it unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os.getcwd()` to get the Current Working Directory. Read up on what this means exactly, fe [here](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Enaraehan/python3/file_path_cwd.html)

See the sample script below on how to use it. I'm using `os.sep` for OS agnostic filepath separators.

```py
import os


print(os.getcwd())

relative_path = "data"
full_path = f"{os.getcwd()}{os.sep}{relative_path}"
print(full_path)

filename = "somefile.csv"
full_file_path = f"{full_path}{os.sep}{filename}"
print(full_file_path)

with open(full_file_path) as infile:
    for line in infile.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In which directory are you standing when you are running your code?

From your error message I would assume that you are standing in `/Users/myname/` which makes python look for `data` as a subdirectory of `/Users/myname/`.

But if you first change directory to `/Users/myname/Documents/Master2/Python/Final_Project` and then run your code from there I think it would work.